# Update function

Tags: java, android, events

I try to learn java for android devices..
i have to create the update function. But still have one question: How????

in class root

```
public void update(){
 maindebug("update"); // This is my debug function
}

public void run(){
 while(isRunning){ // isRunning is a boolean variable
     SystemClock.sleep(100);
  update();
 }
}
```

and inside onCreate

```
run();
```

but it doesnt work :(

Comment: Perhaps you'd better describe your goals here.  What you're trying to do isn't very apparent.

Comment: My english is very bad. I need function which updates every 100 ms.

Answer (score 0):

`isRunning` must evaluate to "true" for your while loop to happen.